# Можно ли изменить/дополнить pull request?

Tags: git, github, pull-request

Недавно начал работать в компании. Схема работы такова:

1. Под задачу создаётся отдельная ветка
2. После того, как задача была завершена, делается pull request на master
3. Pull request проверяется и если всё ок, мёрджится в мастер

После того, как я завершил свою задачу, я сделал pull request на master. В комментариях написали замечания к некоторым частям моего кода. Я исправил то, что требовалось, но не знаю, как поступить. Мне закрыть предыдущий pull request и отправить новый, или же можно как-то изменить старый?

Comment: Просто пушьте в ту же ветку, чего мудрить

Comment: @andreymal После того, как я запушу изменения в мою ветку, пулл реквест тоже поменяется? Я почему-то думал, что в пулл реквесте останутся те изменения, которые были сделаны до того, как я его отправлю, а на те изменения, что я запушил после того, как пулл реквест был отправлен придётся снова делать пулл реквест. Можете пожалуйста чуть подробнее описать этот процесс.

Comment: Поменяется. . .

Comment: @andreymal Окей, спасибо

Comment: andreymal правильно написал. В дополнение скажу, что исправления нужно делать в той же ветке, из которой изначально делался PR новыми комитами (т.е. не нужно использовать git push --force), чтоб история комментариев к PR не пропала и комментаторам легче было проверить, что вы все исправили и все замечания учли.